# Parsing ESRI Shapefiles in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, shapefile, esri

So I currently am trying to get some map data that is being given by a 3rd party provider. They have given us nothing except the data dump, so no documentation or a point of contact to see what they were using prior.

I have 4 files:

`30083_parcel.dbf`

`30083_parcel.prj`

`30083_parcel.shp`

`30083_parcel.shx`

Now, without going into unnecessary detail I have already managed to extract out and get working data from the `dbf` `prj` and `shp` files. However, I am having a lot of trouble with `shx`.

Per Wikipedia's entry on the specification for SHX files:

```
The index contains the same 100-byte header as the .shp file, followed by any number of 8-byte fixed-length records which consist of the following two fields:

Bytes   Type    Endianness  Usage
0–3 int32   big Record offset (in 16-bit words)
4–7 int32   big Record length (in 16-bit words)
```

So, I tried something along these lines:

```
File.open('test.txt') do|file|
  until file.eof?
    buffer = file.read(100)
    # Do something with buffer
    puts buffer
  end
end
```

And all I'm getting is some crazy characters, like 
`H`, `�`, and `P`. I am not sure where to go to get anything further to usefully retrieve the record offset and record length.

Any ideas? I thought by using the `file.read(100)` that I would get the headers and atleast be able to see them, but that is not the case. And after trying to access the rest after that first 100 bytes, I am getting similar random unicode.

Its at a point where I'd be open to non-ruby solutions, as well.

Comment: Few ideas for resources: [esri whitepaper about shapefiles](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf), a blog post about [shapefiles in ruby](http://www.andresblog.net/ruby-on-rails/opening-a-shapefile-using-ruby-on-rails/), and [some code on github that might help](https://github.com/nofxx/georuby/)

Answer (score 0):

The `shp` file is the geometry, is in a binary format, and includes bug endian and little endian integer and floats.

The `shx` file is the optional index file, and as such is very simple, and mainly big endian.

Is it that the shapefile has been read by a tool, library or an existing program, but the `shx` is not being used?  Your solution is not to use it, or point the other tool to it's existence.

It's a optimisation for reading the records out of the `shp` file, so it not needed, or can be recreated by parsing the shapefile.

But if you did need it then open the file in `binary mode` and covert the 2 byte big endian values to the offset, and length.

The crazy characters are from reading it, or displaying it as `ASCII`, as a picture tells a thousand words:

[image: Hex Edit view of shp and shx file]

Look at row 96 (`decimal`), the highlight on the left in blue is the `shp` Record `0x000001` and it's length ( 1 = 2 bytes) is `0x0002c8`, and the left is the `shx` index, offset for Record 1 is `0x32`, which is `50` 2 bytes pairs, thus `100` bytes into the file and the record length, again, of `0x2c8`, or `0x590` bytes.

The crazy characters are the `ASCII` representation of these and is meaningless, this is the narrow column to the right of the hex numbers, mainly `.`'s

Note the Record Info is Big endian, hence the file 2 bytes `0x 00 00 27 0A` corresponds to the spec the `FILE CODE` which is given as `9994` (`decimal`).

The values within the `shp` records themselves, and the bounding box in the header (first 100 bytes) are little endian.

[edited as I initial had my little and big endian swapped around]